# How to check all usages of a domain property in intellij?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, refactoring

Suppose i have a domain class

```
class Event{
  String name
  String address
  Date startDate
  Director director
}
```

I want to check the usages of the director property. I want to know how many places the property is being used. This will help me with the refactor decision. In other words if the property is not being used much i can remove it and come up with other alternatives.

Is there a way to do such analysis in intellij? Doing this manually in a large system or application is very hard and it is likely we can miss some places where it is used. So i appreciate some guide from experts if there is an efficient way to do this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you need something other than `ALT` + `F7` (on Windows) which gives you the opportunity to to look for both direct access and accessor calls (get/set)? Is there a specific thing you're looking for that can not be dug-out by `Find usages`?

Comment: thanks. i didnt notice that intellij has direct Usages option to show all usages. This will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `SHIFT` + `F7` for a couple more options when finding usages, Also, [here's the official default keymap for win & linux](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)